# Accelerometer data analysis without FFT

Tags: signal-analysis

I have a device (Large as typical PC casing) with a motor. There can be a condition that the device motor load is unbalanced and the device starts to move around the table and I need to detect this. For this, I have an accelerometer.

But the problem is that I can't come up with a reliable algorithm to detect these vibrations.

Here are sensor data. The solid line is 5 point moving average. The dotted line is raw data. Time is in ms.

[image]

I tried to do some averaging, max and min detection and some other simple algorithms but it didn't work, but there is difference between plots, "Vibration" plot looks more periodic and consist of one frequency.

Can you please suggest some algorithms or ways to deal with such a problem in the time domain?
Maybe there is some neat way to differentiate these two plots?

I am using 8bit MCU to read data and detect vibrations so I can't do real-time frequency domain analysis.

Thank you

PS.
I will add plots I made in the frequency domain, maybe this will help.
I took 5 points moving average. Then used a cosine hamming window and took DFT of 64 samples.
Here are plots

Vibrations
[image]

No vibrations

[image]

Comment: First, this is 2020.  When you buy an 8-bit processor or a small 32-bit ARM-based processor, you're paying more for the pins than you are for the silicon.  **Change your processor**.

Comment: When you say "an 8-bit processor" that covers a pretty wide range -- an 8051 with a 1MHz clock?  An AtMega with a 40MHz clock?  Something in between?  How willing are you to write assembly code to speed up the math?

Comment: @TimWescott Yeah, I know. But in this project, I need to work on already existing hardware and PCB, hardware changes are not possible.

Comment: @TimWescott The MCU is PIC16f series with clock speed 8Mhz. But my main question is: Is there some methods on how to process the accelerometer data without FFT. Maybe some good reading material on this topic. Because everywhere I read about vibration analysis there are two options: 1. Simple threshold and 2. FFT.  
Maybe someone can give good reading material on the topic...